# Randomly generating different list from list

Tags: python, arrays, random

first I created a list called “citys” then it tried to swap randomly two elements in the “citys” list for 5 times and at the same time tried to store the new lists in the “number_of_citys” but it turns out bad every time it loops, it insert the last swapped arrays only.
I used this randomly generated list ,
citys= [[1,2], [3,4],[1,3],[5,2]] , to create another list. And I expected my list to be,
orders_of_citys=[[[1,2], [5,2],[1,3][3,4]] , [[5,2], [1,2],[1,3][3,4]],[ [1,3], [1,2],[5,2][3,4]], [[3,4], [1,2],[5,2][1,3]], [1,3], [1,2],[5,2][3,4]] ]
but I got the following
order_of_citys =[[[1,3], [1,2],[5,2][3,4]], [1,3], [1,2],[5,2][3,4]], [1,3], [1,2],[5,2][3,4]] ,[1,3], [1,2],[5,2][3,4]], [1,3], [1,2],[5,2][3,4]]]
I have used append(), +=, and insert built in function and operators but I still get the same array. please I would like some one to point me my problem.The code I wrote is the following.

```
import random
  
citys = []
number_of_cities = 5
orders_of_citys = []
pop = 5

#give random place for cities on 2D plane
for i in range(number_of_cities):
        citys.append( [ random.randint(0, 1000), random.randint(0, 1000)])

#suffle  points (citys) position to get different path
def swap(c, a, b):
        value = c[a]
        c[a] = c[b]
        c[b] = value
        return c

for j in range(pop):
    a = random.randint(0, len(citys)-1)
    b= random.randint(0, len(citys)-1)
    new_path = swap(citys, a, b)
    orders_of_citys.append(new_path)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your swap function is literally modifying the array, not returning a new array.  So `orders_of_citys` contains five copies of the exact same array, and any time you. modify one of those arrays using `swap`, you're modifying all of them.

If you really want to see what's going on, change the last line to be

```
orders_of_citys.append(new_path[:])
```

which makes a copy of the array and then appends it to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `new_path` is actually a reference to `citys`, and you append the reference. Once the `citys` is changed, all the referred data will be changed too, so it have the same data.

And the solution is to make a deep copy of the array and append the copy.

```py
from copy import deepcopy

# Other codes

def swap(c, a, b):
    d = deepcopy(c)
    value = d[a]
    d[a] = d[b]
    d[b] = value
    return d
```

The solution above is more easier. I'm late QwQ